# How do I save the progress already made in an app?

Tags: android, android-studio, autosave

I'm doing a quiz where the user unlocked the levels, but when he closes the app all progress is lost, and he has to redo everything again. How can I fix this and make the user's progress automatically saved? Or with it by clicking a button, I do not know

Comment: It`s your choice. if your quiz is a local app use SQLite, SharedPrefference or anything. 
Or your quiz is a online app use server and save the process in server using webservice.

Comment: Well... how to save information in android is a large topic. You can check this link about sharedPreferences: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html. Or this one about sqlite: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Fr099y. my quiz is local, can you give me an example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save it in **SharedPreferences** and check the value of it every time application is opened.

To save value:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("YourFileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    //YourFileName= Any file name you give it 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("levels", your_level_value);    //levels=key at which data is stored, your_level_value=No. of levels completed
editor.apply();
```

To retrieve value:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("YourFileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    //YourFileName= Any file name you give it
String levelCompleted = sp.getString("levels", "0");     //levels=key at which no. of levels is saved.
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I save activity the way it is?

Comment: You need to save that data too.